# Resize an image with 54x54 squares (540x540) to 54x54pixel lossless

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing, imagemagick-convert

I've got an 540x540 image of 54x54 color squares (same sizes).

When I resize it to 54x54px it looks horrible (blurred), shouldn't a resize like this be perfectly done with imagemagick?

is I possible to get it perfect?

I've tested `convert source.png -resize destination.png` and `-adaptive-resize`  but the result is the same..

Comment: There are some filters for use with resize and a good explanation of some here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/

Comment: @Bonzo read it, tested a few, but it just gets blurry..

Comment: Resizing by a large amount (10 to 1) will be blurry. Perhaps you want -sample, which will take one pixel per square or -scale which will do a simple average of all the pixels in a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your confusion is now... the problem is not that the process is lossy, rather it is because the `-resize` is doing more sophisticated processing than you want in order to make an attractive job that you would want for, say, photographs. You want a very simple point sampling process which will produce simple blocks of pure, uncombined colour.

I'll make a start image:

```
magick -size 10x10 xc:red +noise random -scale 540x540 start.png
```

[image]

And scale it down, by taking a point sample in each block:

```
magick start.png -sample 10x10 small.png
```

[image]

And back up:

```
magick result.png -scale 540x540 reincarnated.png
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps he needs -sample rather than -scale. Same result if the blocks are constant color

Comment: @fmw42 .. how do you suggest I should use it?

Comment: @fmw42 Ooops! I omitted the crucial line when I wrote up the answer during a commercial break late last night 

Comment: @MarkSetchell don't you need to use -sample to enlarge it to?, I don't get so clean colors when using scale..

Comment: If you click `edit` under your question and update it with your images, your current and expected result, it will all be much easier. At the moment you are forcing us to guess.